# DNS reply to redirect client to another DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-dns

I have a client which uses a DNS server (ServerA), and ServerA works fine for all domains

For a specific domain though, I need to use a DNS Server (ServerB) which ServerA cannot access, but the client can.

The Windows client is unable to use domain based selection criteria for DNS servers AFAIK, so I would like to get ServerA to respond to the client with a message that says "for this domain and all subdomains, use ServerB".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to configure things exactly as you've described. DNS servers don't work like that.

Typically, this is done by configuring your client to use ServerB as its DNS server instead of ServerA. Then, you configure ServerB to forward all requests for zones it does not own to ServerA (there are a couple ways to do this depending on the DNS software). When the client asks ServerB for things it does not own, ServerB asks ServerA and then ServerB returns the result to the client with some additional metadata that tells the client it got the answer from someone else (a "non-authoritative" answer).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case but wanted some expert clarification